# Dynamicaly fill table td based on array of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to fill the background of table td based on td values. Below is the sample code i wrote for filling the td cell value.

```js
applySchedules = function(schedules){
    $.map(schedules, function(value, index){   
        $('#'+value.start).css('background', 'green');
    });
}

var temp = [{start:9, end:10}, {start:13, end:14}]
applySchedules(temp);
```

```css
tr {
   border-width:2px; 
   outline:solid;
}
td {
   border-width:2px; 
   width:60px; 
   outline:solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="8">8AM</td>
        <td id="9">9AM</td>
        <td id="10">10AM</td>
        <td id="11">11AM</td>
        <td id="12">12PM</td>
        <td id="13">1PM</td>
        <td id="14">2PM</td>
        <td id="15">3PM</td>
        <td id="16">4PM</td>
        <td id="17">5PM</td>
        <td id="18">6PM</td>
        <td id="19">7PM</td>
        <td id="20">8PM</td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Basically i will get json array of time slots that are occupied for the given day. The problem comes when the slot span more than or less than 1hour. The time slots are allotted in multiple's 30 mins.

Like `{start:10,end:11.30},{start:12,end:12.30},{start:14.30,end:15}`

Looking for some pointers how to handle these kind of cases.

Sample Output : [image]

Comment: In that case increase the number of `td` so that each block is 30 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise:

1. increase number of spans such way, that there would be your 30 minute item
2. Don't use just numbered ID's -> it is not a very good way

```js
$(function(){
   var applySchedules = function(schedules){
    $.map(schedules, function( value,index){  
         
         var startHour = value.start.split(":")[0];
         var endHour = value.end.split(":")[0];
         var halfStart = value.start.split(":")[1];
         var halfEnd = value.end.split(":")[1];
         
         var startContainer = $('#time'+ padLeft( startHour, 2));
         var endContainer = $('#time'+ padLeft( endHour, 2));
     
             if( parseInt( halfStart  )){
               startContainer.append( $("<div />").addClass("start") );
             }
             if( parseInt( halfEnd  )){
               endContainer.append( $("<div />").addClass("end") );
             }
         
          if( ( parseInt(endHour) - parseInt(startHour) ) > 0){
            for( var i = 1; i < parseInt(endHour) - parseInt(startHour); i++ ){
              
               $('#time'+ padLeft( (parseInt(startHour) + i)+"", 2)).append( $("<div />").addClass("full") );
            }
          }
         
    });
   }
   function padLeft(str,size,padwith) {
 if(size <= str.length) {
  return str;
 } else {
  return Array(size-str.length+1).join(padwith||'0')+str
 }
   }
  
   
   var initTime = function(){
     for( var i =0; i< 24; i++ ){
       var $item;
       if( i < 12  ){
         $item = $("<td/>").text( padLeft(i+"",2)+":00 AM" );
       }else if( i == 12 ){
         $item = $("<td/>").text( padLeft( (i)+"",2)+":00 PM" );
       } else {
         $item = $("<td/>").text( padLeft( (i-12)+"",2)+":00 PM" );
       }
       $item.attr("id", "time" + padLeft(i+"",2));
       $("#timeContainer").append($item);
     }   
   }
   
   var temp=[{start:"9:00",end:"9:30"}, {start:"13:00",end:"13:30"}, { start:"14:00", end:"14:30"}, {start:"15:30", end:"18:30"}]
   initTime();
  applySchedules(temp);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
tr{border-width:2px; outline:solid;}
td{border-width:2px; width:60px; outline:solid; position:relative;}
  div.start {
      width: 50%;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index:-1;
}
div.end {
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  z-index:-1;
}
  div.full{
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index:-1;
  }
  
</style>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr id="timeContainer">
  </tr> 
 </table>

</body>
```

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**
Some first approach to code

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan & xAqweRx for quick suggestion. Just for to explain i mentioned time 8AM-8PM. But its a 24 hour slot selection and user wants it in 1 hour span, to avoid long scrolling.

And i need to color multiple td's when the time slot occupies more than 1 hour ie {start:12.30,end:15}.

Comment: @SudheerEega what cell should be colored if time is 12.30 ? 12:00 or 13:00?

Comment: It should be cell 12.00 and coloring of td second half(50% width).

Comment: Thanks xAqweRx for the sample code. I'm looking something dynamically add days(next 3,7 or 15) to scheduler so that users can check available slots. I just updated my post with sample screen shot.

Comment: This is the other situation. You should add dynamically cells with date and time IDS and manage this in `map` function

Answer (score 0):

If you are adamant on using your current setup, might I suggest using CSS gradients:

```
...
$('#'+value.start).css('background','repeating-linear-gradient(to right, #00FF33, #00FF33 23px, #FFFFFF 23px, #FFFFFF 46px)');
...
```

46px is the width of the `<td>` in the fiddle, this would probably have to be generated dynamically. The second two values are half of the width of the whole `<td>` which creates a gradient covering only half of the whole `<td>`. You can then split this into smaller section by doing more complicated maths but I suggest referring to https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/ for more information on this trick.

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/85mJN/190/